# Doxygen - Latex enumerate list item doesn't show properly

Tags: latex, doxygen, pdflatex

I have generated latex using Doxygen, I want to edit some pages and add an enumerate list in there, when I edit it, it doesn't show properly, it's like being overwritten with text there.

- here is the code
  [latex-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYS73.png)
- here is the result
  [latex-pdf-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzWP8.png)

can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which version of LaTeX are you using? Never post code as as images always post it as code in the question (so we can cut/paste it to do experiments). Please provide the differences of the doxygen settings you used compared to the default settings (`doxygen -x`). The latex code is a result, please post a small, reproducible, source code example.